# Two objects persisted with one table (first is aggregated by second)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I have following table:

```
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers 
-----------+---------+-----------
 palett_id | integer | not null
 x         | integer | not null
 y         | integer | not null
 sequence  | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "slots_palett_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (palett_id)
    "slots_x_y_sequence_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (x, y, sequence)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "slots_palett_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (palett_id) REFERENCES palettes(palett_id)
```

Now I would like to create two objects from it:

Slot:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Slot.TABLE)
public class Slot implements Serializable {
    public static final String TABLE = "slots";
    public static final String COORDINATE_X = "x";
    public static final String COORDINATE_Y = "y";
    public static final String SEQUENCE = "sequence";

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = Palett.ID)
    private Palett palett;

    @Id
    @Column(name = Slot.SEQUENCE)
    private byte position;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = Slot.COORDINATE_X), @JoinColumn(name = Slot.COORDINATE_Y)})
    @JsonIgnore
    private Stack stack;
}
```

and Stack, composed from slots:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Slot.TABLE)
public class Stack {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Coordinates coordinates;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stack", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy(value = Slot.SEQUENCE + " ASC")
    private List<Slot> slots;

    public Stack() {}

    public Stack(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.slots = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addSlot(Slot s) {
        this.slots.add(s);
        s.setStack(this);
        s.setPosition((byte) this.slots.size());
    }
}
```

I got also object Coordinates:

```
@Embeddable
public class Coordinates implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = Slot.COORDINATE_X)
    private int x;

    @Column(name = Slot.COORDINATE_Y)
    private int y;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public Coordinates(){}
}
```

My problem is, that object slot have three-field key (x,y,sequence), while I would like to reference it from stack which have two-field key (x,y). So I got following error:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKjcydeens7h0219w5bwf075hpc:slots [x,y])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (slots [x,y,sequence])`

Is there anyway to implement that with JPA, without creation of two tables?:

```
 stacks (id, x, y)
 slots(stack_id, sequence, palett_id)
```

When I remove `@Id` from `private byte position` code compiles correctly, but results are incorrect (if there is two slots in one stack, I got 2 element list with duplicated elements - first one), ie:

```
palett_id, x, y, sequence
    1      1  1     1
    2      1  1     2
```

Then as result I got:

```
Stack -> Slot(id = 1), Slot(id=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that you have entity `Stack` defined to use the same table as `Slot` (for some reason). One of them has a PK of (byte,Stack) and the other has a PK of (int,int). Totally incompatible

Comment: Yes I know. Stack is different way to present Slots (grouped by coordinates). I could implement two separate tables, but it doesn't make sense if Stacks is just groups of slots. That's why I asked if there is any way to implement that with one table.

Comment: using an RDBMS view perhaps is the only way I would contemplate

Comment: Hah. The point is that, view gives you ability to select only. I would like to persist data as well. :/

Comment: What about @MapsId annotation? Would it help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @neil-stockton suggestion and created following view:

```
create or replace view stacks as select distinct x,y from slots;
```